# How to divide React Bootstrap card in 3 columns when mapping

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I wanted to achieve my items in 3 bootstrap columns when mapping the data. Is this possible anyhow? My data will come in one particular column, if I call my props data again in another column, those will repeat. How can I divide them in 3 columns?

I want like this:

1    2    3

4    5    6

7    8    9

I get like this:

1

2

3

4

5

6

...

Is there any fix? Or any CSS code that might help?

```
const Meals = (props) => {
    const {meals} = props;
  return (
    <div>
        {meals?.map((meal) => {
            return <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col md={4}>
                <img src={meal.image} alt="" />
                <h1>{meal.title}</h1>
                <p>{meal.desc}</p>
                <p>{meal.price}</p>
              </Col>
              <Col md={4}>
              </Col>
              <Col md={4}>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        })}
    </div>
  )
}
```